# insert for $out failed

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My documents in my DB are stored an array of results for each user.

**Data types:**

```
age: {type: Number}, 
gender: {type: String},
result: [{ game: String,time: Number, level: Number, mistakes: Number,moves: Number }]
```

In order to analyze my data I want to `unwind` the results,
For example the following document:

```
{"_id":"5ce58a662f6fcb3b782013e3","age":10,"gender":"Male","result":[{"_id":"5ce58a662f6fcb3b782013e9","game":"puzzle","time":20,"level":3,"mistakes":5,"moves":50},{"_id":"5ce58a662f6fcb3b782013e8","game":"puzzle","time":20,"level":3,"mistakes":5,"moves":50},{"_id":"5ce58a662f6fcb3b782013e7","game":"puzzle","time":20,"level":3,"mistakes":5,"moves":50},{"_id":"5ce58a662f6fcb3b782013e6","game":"memory","time":20,"level":3,"mistakes":5,"moves":50},{"_id":"5ce58a662f6fcb3b782013e5","game":"memory","time":20,"level":3,"mistakes":5,"moves":50},{"_id":"5ce58a662f6fcb3b782013e4","game":"memory","time":20,"level":3,"mistakes":5,"moves":50}],"__v":0}]
```

will be devided to a 6 docs, and stored on a new collection with the same **userId**.

I've tried to run:

```
 db.userschemes.aggregate([{ "$unwind": "$result"},{ $out : "newcollection" }])
```

but got the following:

> assert: command failed: {
>           "ok" : 0,
>           "errmsg" : "insert for $out failed: { connectionId: 1, err: \"E11000 dup licate key error index: vpdata.tmp.agg_out.2.$*id* dup
>   key: { : ObjectId('5ce58a 662f6fcb3b782013e3') }\", code: 11000, n: 0,
>   ok: 1.0 }",
>           "code" : 16996 } : aggregate failed
>   _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13 doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
>   assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:290:5
>   DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5
>   @(shell):1:1
>
> 2019-05-26T19:04:05.395+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command
>   failed: {
>           "ok" : 0,
>           "errmsg" : "insert for $out failed: { connectionId: 1, err: \"E11000 dup licate key error index: vpdata.tmp.agg_out.2.$*id* dup
>   key: { : ObjectId('5ce58a 662f6fcb3b782013e3') }\", code: 11000, n: 0,
>   ok: 1.0 }",
>           "code" : 16996 } : aggregate failed :
>   _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13 doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
>   assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:290:5
>   DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5
>   @(shell):1:1

How can I avoid this? I'm understand the issue that I have multiple docs with the same id but this is exactly what I want.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$out` you're creating new collection named `newcollection`. MongoDB requires every `_id` to be unique. That constraint cannot be dropped, so as you're `$unwind`-ing an array there might be duplicated `_id` values in a final result set.

As a workaround you can introduce `$project` stage and move current _id into different field so that there will be no unique constraint on it. MongoDB will generate new `_id` values for all documents, try:

```
db.userschemes.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$result"},     
    { $addFields: { userId : "$_id" } },
    { $project: { _id: 0 } },
    { $out : "newcollection" }
])
```